# Access local content of user on web server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a kind of weird question but I hope you will take this seriously.

I have content that is placed on my local machine e.g. c:\folder\images. And I have website www.example.com. Now, I have to show content(c:\folder\images) on hitting www.example.com/list without uploading this content. I think it's possible because users can see their own content if web server knows their content's path. But I don't know how.

Can you guys have any idea how to do it?

Comment: is the www.example.com website hosted on your machine?

Comment: No. You can't. "users can see their own content if web server knows their content's path" - false. Two different machines in a network need to somehow _explicitlty_ share resources between them. Thus the question above.

Comment: @Traian No it's not on my machine. It's actually hosted on godaddy.com

Comment: @Sergiu I got you but i guess user is on client side and we have content to show on local machine. if somehow server knows path of that content we should be able to display or use it. What do you say?

Comment: Not possible. The browser explicitly restricts access to local resources other than cookies, local storage (in all it's variants) and the file upload input. You cannot even use `file://some_absolute_local_path`, it's also explicitly restricted.